# Какие сейчас популярны методы позиционирования элементов HTML на странице сайта

Tags: html5, вёрстка, позиционирование

Flexbox, CSS Grid, position: absolute;, относительное позиционирование, резиновый макет, фиксированный, float's - голова кругом идет.

Понятно, что сейчас нужен адаптивный (раз!) и интерактивный (два!) сайт, заточенный под широкий круг устройств.

Но как найти верное решение позиционирования?

Какое использовать, чтобы время погружения в понимание предмета было не очень длительным и чтобы это решение было наиболее эффективное для разработки мульти-страничного современного сайта.

Получается такой вот философский вопрос.

Какие решения используете вы?

Посоветуйте, новичку.

Comment: Инструмент подбирается по задаче.

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ. 
Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ (или удалить вовсе).

Comment: Соглашусь с **@andreymal**. Раз вы новичок, то советую узнать о всех, перечисленных вами, включая "методы" вёрстки (фиксированный, адаптивный и прочее). Углубится советую в [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) и [Grid Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы только начинаете изучение, то для начала посмотрите что такое
[translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate), с его помощью Вы, например, сможете просто и эффективно позиционировать объекты по центру:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Далее рекомендую изучить [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), на данный момент это самый мощный и современный подход к организации layout'a.

На Июль 2020 года он [поддерживается](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) не так "глубоко" (iOS 10.3 и выше), но это всего лишь вопрос времени. Если у Вас нет задач поддерживать старые системы то это оптимальный выбор так как понимая `Grid` Вы уже без проблем будете понимать как работать с `Flex` и пр.